# How to know if all $http calls are over - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I need to trigger an event when all of my $http calls are processed. I also need to know if any call has failed. I tried using the available solutions on stackoverflow such as using an interceptor.

```
angular.module('app').factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope',
  function ($q, $rootScope) {
    var loadingCount = 0;

    return {
      request: function (config) {
        if(++loadingCount === 1) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:progress');
        }
        return config || $q.when(config);
      },    
      response: function (response) {
        if(--loadingCount === 0) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:finish');
        }
        return response || $q.when(response);
      },    
      responseError: function (response) {
        if(--loadingCount === 0) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:finish');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
  }
]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);
```

However, with this approach the `$rootScope.$broadcast('loading:finish')` gets called after every $http call is completed. I want to trigger an event when all the $http calls are over.

I cannot use `$q` since the `$http` calls in my page belong to various directives and are not called in the same controller.

Comment: you can make use of '$http.pendingRequests'. You can check if $http.pendingRequests.length !== 0;

Comment: you can create a service to hold all those $http calls, since $http calls return promise, this service is a collection of promise, so you just need to write like: Promise.all(....)

Comment: @ABOS, I will read about Promise.all() and try it. Will get back to you with questions though! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to check the number of pending requests for $http. I am using this to show loading spinner in my project.

```
$http.pendingRequests.length
```

For keeping a track of failed and success calls you can use something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function ($rootScope){
  $rootScope.failedCalls = 0;
  $rootScope.successCalls = 0;
 })
.controller('MyCtrl', 
function($log, $scope, myService) {
 $scope.getMyListing = function(employee) {
   var promise = 
       myService.getEmployeeDetails('employees');
   promise.then(
      function(payload) { 
          $scope.listingData = payload.data;
          $rootScope.successCalls++; //Counter for success calls
      },
      function(errorPayload) {
        $log.error('failure loading employee details', errorPayload);
        $rootScope.failedCalls++; //Counter for failed calls
      });
 };
 })
 .factory('myService', function($http) {
  return {
  getEmployeeDetails: function(id) {
     return $http.get('/api/v1/employees/' + id);
  }
}
 });
```

Basically I have created 2 root scope variables and using it as counters to maintain count of success and failed calls which you can use wherever you want.

Comment: @talentedandrew - This is what I am using currently. However, there is no way to know if any of my calls failed. I need to trigger the event only on successful completion of all $http calls.

Comment: Interceptors would be the best way to find out number of failed and successful calls.

Comment: @InquisitiveP I have updated my answer to solve your second problem as well. Please have a look.